# Nameservers and DNS - Appropriate Steps to Move to A VPS?

Tags: dns, vps, nameserver, best-practices, migration

I bought a VPS and I am trying to transfer my domain over to the new server, I took two steps so far, but I don't think I did it quite right as its been 24 hours and most all DNS check sites still indicate errors with my name-servers. Here is what I have done so far,

- Made new nameservers in my namecheap account
- (`ns1.domain.com`) and (`ns2.domain.com`) with the same IP as my VPS only has one IP.
- Then I went in and changed the name servers for the domain itself to the newly made name-servers.

Is there any more to be done? The VPS does not have cPanel, and this is my first time setting up LAMP, and dealing straight from the command line for everything without the help of WHM or cPanel. Thanks everyone,
 necro.

Comment: `ns1.domain.com` would seem to be the nameserver for domain.com, not namecheap. If you were trying to refer to a nonexistent example domain in place of your own, please use `example.com`, `example.net`, or `example.org` (as per [RFC 2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606)).

Comment: As for your question, the steps are the same as any other type of hosting. You generally want to set a low TTL for your DNS records prior to the migration if you can anticipate the move. This helps the changes propagate faster if done early enough. If your NS' hostnames reside in the very domain name they're hosting, then the proper glue records will need to have been created in the parent zone. But your registrar generally takes care of this. Aside from that, just make sure your new nameservers have the correct DNS records and are up.

Comment: I'd also agree that you want to set a low TTL. Hopefully you'll have control over this, as some hosts force TTL's of a few hours. Amazon Route 53 is one service I use and recommend for DNS management.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're running your own DNS server (typically BIND), you don't need to muck about with your nameserver settings inside of namescheap.  Running BIND is a fairly complicated matter requiring significant DNS engineering skills, so it's unlikely that this is your situation.

I would suggest restoring your domain's nameserver settings back to normal and modifying the correct Host records to point to your new VPS:

1. Inside of Namecheap's "Manage Domains" panel, click "Transfer DNS to Webhost" and select "Use Namecheap Hosting DNS Servers" and Save.
2. Under "Nameserver Registration", delete the IP address from all listed name servers.  This will remove any overrides you've configured and default back to the Namescheap DNS servers.
3. Under "All Host Records", change the 'www' record to point to your VPS IP.  If your '@' record is of type 'A (Address)', you should enter your IP there as well and click Save Changes.

Answer (score 2):

You have long way to go now. You'll need to understand DNS thoroughly. Just buy any good DNS book( DNS and BIND, 5th Edition - O'Reilly Media is good enough) and learn how to configure it. You can use Webmin to configure you VPS but it's little buggy. I also tried like you, but later switched to Managed VPS with Cpanel due to shortage of time(I now pay $27/month for Managed 1GB ram VPS from Soladrive).

In fact with Cpanel doing DNS is easy. Most of values are simply default. To be frank to be fluent in DNS is a network's administrator's job since debugging Bind, setting up, Secondary name servers will be difficult and will divert your effort away from web development activities.

Now you need run DNS server on your VPS using bind. You need to assign it ns1 and ns2 for the same single IP address.

There is alternate solution to use service of third party DNS service providers like dnsmadeeasy.com which are better in every aspect except for cost if you can bear.

But if you want to learn it, then you're on the right path.

Check your dns using intodns.com regularly for any dns issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your dns is updated or not in whois.

Do you have DNS manager interface in your VPS?
Set A / AAA records to redirect your url to that IP.

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one IP you may register only one nameserver. Then install BIND9 or other dns server and add DNS records like cname, mx etc. for your domain here. Suppose you own domain: example.com and ip: 96.7.88.116, here, example.com will be resolved to registered nameserver say: ns.example.com and ns.example.com will resolve to 96.7.88.116.

Alternatively you can use Namecheap's default nameserver to hold dns records of example.com and then add A record pointing to your IP.

```
    example.com.   A   96.7.88.116
```

Further, add following in /etc/hosts file:

```
    96.7.88.116       example.com
```

Create NameBased apache vhosts to host your websites.